# Change android proxy settings

Tags: android, permissions, proxy, settings

i'm trying to write an app that can change the proxy settings on android 2.2.1 but i receive a permission exception.

I execute this within my code:

`Settings.Secure.putString(resolver,Settings.Secure.HTTP_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:8080");`

In the manifest i specified the WRITE_SETTINGS and WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permissions, but i receive this exception.

> Permission denial: writing to secure settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS

I read that only system apps can change these settings directly, how can i change it.

In the apis like 2.0 is seems to work, but in 2.2 the proxy setting was moved to Secure class.

Comment: I would love to know this its a pain having no proxy server settings at all on my nexus.

Answer (score 0):

An app called APNPT changes the settings, you may want to take a peak on the code:

https://github.com/r3pek/APNpt

Comment: Unfortunately this app changes the settings for the umts network not for the wifi. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this library:

https://github.com/shouldit/android-proxy/tree/master/android-proxy-library